# Question about the proof of the irreducibility of cyclotomic polynomials in Dummit & Foote

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

In section 13.6, there is this proof:

[image: text]

My question is about the highlighted portions. It is to my understanding that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not an ED, and we cannot do division here. But how did the authors just assume that we have a factorization here? Is it because of Gauss' Lemma? (If so, how exactly was the logic applied?)

I am assuming that the two highlighted portions have the same reasoning, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: An element $a$ in an arbitrary ring is reducible if $a=bc$ with non-unit elements $b, c$, and irreducible otherwise. That's the definition.

Comment: As you say, there's an implicit appeal to Gauss's lemma here.

Comment: OK thank you for the comments. I think I got it--the first highlight comes from reducibility, and the second highlight has an implicit appeal to Gauss' Lemma